# Connect Amazon EC2 instance to web address and FTP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp

I'm trying to set up a basic test server with a simple ftp connection using EC2.

**So far I have done the following in EC2:**

1. Created an EC2 instance and downloaded my key file.
2. Connected to the EC2 instance using "ec2-user".
3. Uploaded a "Hello World" index.php file into the ec2-user directory.
4. Added an elastic (static) ip address to the instance.
5. Configured the security group to allow inbound and outbound All
   Traffic from anywhere.

**And in Route 53:**

1. Created a hosted zone and associated the nameservers globally from
   my registrar.
2. Set the "A" record to the elastic ip of the instance.

Despite doing all this I get `Error - Connection Refused`

It's an Amazon Linux instance. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to connect using ssh  or ftp? Did you install a FTP server?

Comment: I think I have realised what I did wrong. I would need to have apache and php installed - so I've chosen a LAMP stack from the pre-defined images marketplace. There's a free one :)